# If someone has BO and can't smell themselves, may they say blessings?

Tags: halacha, blessing, smell, showering-bathing, personal-hygiene

<sup>"Just as one separates oneself from excreta, urine, a foul odor, a corpse and the sight of nakedness for *Kri'at Shema*, so too, he should separate himself for *Shemoneh Esreh*". (Rambam. *Hilchos Tefillah* 4:8 [in translation](http://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/920167/jewish/Chapter-Five.htm).) One "should wear suitable clothes when he goes to pray, like one who goes before an important minister". ([Online translation](http://www.yonanewman.org/kizzur/kizzur12.html) of *Kitzur Shulchan Aruch* [12:1](http://www.yonanewman.org/kizzur/kizzur12.html).) The Rambam seems to agree. (*Hilchos Tefillah* 5:5 [in translation](http://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/920167/jewish/Chapter-Five.htm).)</sup>

At hashkafah.com, the user named "critic" [asks](http://www.hashkafah.com/index.php?/topic/6960-making-brachot-in-smelly-places/page__p__141121#entry141121):

> If someone has body odor (BO) and they can't smell themselves, would they be able to make a bracha?

I also wonder: May they say words of Torah?

<sub>If I'd gone jogging in mid-morning, and was meeting an important minister in mid-afternoon, I wouldn't just change. I'd also shower: even though I normally don't notice it, jogging does makes me smell. Before saying blessings to the King of Kings, and before discussing His laws, must I shower?</sub>

<sub>Please cite sources.</sub>

<sub>Related: ["Near a bad smell, one might want to do Sh'ma, the Amidah, blessings, loud study, or silent study. Is halacha equally strict about all five?"](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/29752/near-a-bad-smell-one-might-want-to-do-shma-the-amidah-blessings-loud-study)</sub>

Comment: Is BO a bad odor WRT Torah? It's my impression that it's decay, not sweat, that is the issue. Also, for what it's worth everyone smelled strongly in earlier times.

Comment: Why would this be a problem?

Comment: Well if they do not smell themselves then they do not know they have body odor, then they will not be asking this question?

Comment: Can you please clarify why you think this might (or might not) be an issue? You may not say words of Torah around exposed or olfactorily detectable feces. Otherwise I believe, as others have stated, the only issue would be concentration during prayer.

Comment: @SethJ and YaakovKuperman: Thank you for your comments. In response, I've edited the question.

Comment: unforgettableid, thanks for the edit. Ping @YaakovKuperman.

Comment: There is a whole debate in BRACHOS (Bavli) about citing Shema when there is foul smell. However, if one can not smell themselves, they would not be aware of such smell, hence read Shema any way.
King of kings can not "smell" the way a human would, as no "body" is involved nor a "figure of a body" nonetheless a nose.

Comment: @Guy: Thank you for your comment; it's inspired me to strengthen my question. Shmuel Brin [disputes](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/15718/if-someone-has-bo-and-cant-smell-themselves-may-they-say-blessings#16025) your second sentence. And I've just edited my question to argue against your third sentence.

Comment: Today, I found a responsum entitled ["Davening While Sweaty"](http://www.dinonline.org/2012/06/10/davening-while-sweaty/). But it doesn't seem to address the case where one can't smell one's own BO.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The sefer [*Semeichim Leshomro*](http://books.google.com/books/about/%D7%A9%D7%9E%D7%97%D7%99%D7%9D_%D7%9C%D7%A9%D7%95%D7%9E%D7%A8%D7%95.html?id=KAKdnQEACAAJ) asks if a person with BO may pray.

The author answers:

- He may pray. The odor probably comes from a lack of washing, not from excrement. Since he is probably used to his own smell, based on the [Mishna Brura (86:1)](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=49623&pgnum=229), there wouldn't be a problem.

But wait. It seems to me personally:

- This Mishna Brura implies the opposite: that the criteria for smell is not just what *he himself* is bothered by, but actually what *others* are bothered by. You see, it says that to pray, "one must separate himself from a smelly pit as far as excrement. [However], this is true only if it smells so badly *that people are bothered by the smell*".

Comment: Maybe http://www.dinonline.org/2010/06/15/davening-in-freshly-painted-place/ sheds light on the problem that you raise.

Comment: I don't have a good sense of smell.  Does BO count as just "unpleasant"?  Or does it count as "very foul"?

Comment: Thank you for your answer.  I've offered a bigger bounty, which you might get if you improve your answer enough.  (Or you might not get it.  Maybe someone else will write a better answer than yours.)

Comment: the link to Semeichim Leshomro doesn't seem to be working

Comment: [R' Yaakov Sasson](http://www.halachayomit.co.il/EnglishAboutUs.asp) seems to agree one's own perceptions don't matter. He [writes](http://www.halachayomit.co.il/EnglishDisplayRead.asp?readID=1752): "One may not pray or speak words of Torah in a place where there is an offensive odor such as in the presence of a sewer leak, in a place where there are fields fertilized with animal manure, or in the presence of a child with a dirty diaper. "*Even if the specific individual wanting to pray does not smell the offensive odor, so long as other people do, he may not pray there.*" (Emphasis mine.)

Answer (score 5):

The issue is whether the smell bothers you, and will ruin your concentration.

[Eruvin 65a](http://hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=3&daf=65&format=pdf) says that R. Samuel did not pray in a house that contained beer, because the smell bothered him. And R. Papa did not pray in a house that contained fish.

So, if your BO isn't gross to you, it shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: that may be lechumra, not lekula